# Bricked my computer by accident - need help repairing

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, laptop, repair

So I've bricked my pc by disabling all HID devices, so I can't do anything. Right now I'm using a installation USB that I have booted off to try and reverse my changes (using devcon.exe), but after using the repair cmd to turn all HID devices back on, I booted up windows to find that it's all off again. How can I save changes?

Comment: Random thought: connect usb mouse/keyboard you never used before, it should be enabled by default.

Comment: @PTwr The actual USB ports are disabled - not the device connected to it

Comment: Would comment but not enough rep. Is your keyboard disabled? If not, access device manager by pressing windows+run and typing devmgmt.msc Navigate by using tab and arrow keys

Comment: This is one of the reasons I always set my machines so that I can log into them remotely. If you lose the keyboard, graphics, or anything similar, you can get in to fix it.

Comment: you could try using psexec from another computer to run cmd.exe or regedit. see here for info on the registery entries related to USB hardware: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj649944(v=vs.85).aspx . if you don't have another computer, consider an offline registery editor boot disk like BartPE or the venerable NT offline password editor: http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/ . be careful though, this stuff is easy to mess up.